# Foreach on Multiple 2 Dimensional Lists:

Tags: python, arrays, list, iterator

Here's an example of the problem I'm running into:

```
A = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
]

B = [
    ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
    ['7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'],
    ['13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18']
]

for a, b in A, B:
    for ai, bi in a, b:
        if ai == int(bi):
            print 'it worked!'
```

This code gives me an error on line 13: `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.

What I would like to happen is to have `a` and `b` point to the lists of 6 elements, e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']`, respectively, for the first iteration.

I've tried having one iterator for each 2D array, like above, and I've also tried using 12 variables, in case Python was trying to pass each element in the 6-element lists to it's own variable (6 for `a` and 6 for `b`, as in `a1, ... a6, b1, ... b6`

Could anyone point out what's going on here and perhaps explain how to get the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    if a == map(int, b):
        print 'it worked!'
```

If you want to print a single `it worked!` you can do:

```
if all(a == map(int, b) for a, b in zip(A, B)):
    print 'it worked!'
```

`zip` returns a list of pairs whose length is the minimum of the two lists, so it will say it worked for these:

```
A = [[1, 2]]
B = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4']]
```

If you want to avoid this you can `import itertools` and replace `zip` with [`izip_longeset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

Comment: Thanks! I forgot a about the zip function, and I hadn'the even realized that I forgot to map the intended function, so I'll correct that in my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate through multiple lists at the same time, you need to use `zip` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for a, b in zip(A,B):
    # a and b are now the inner lists
    print "It worked!"
```

I'm not sure what you want to achieve with your `a == int(b)` statement, so I left it out.